# ADD and DROP triggers frequently on a database

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I have a table from which I am deleting the data. Whenever a row is deleted, the row matching the data from other tables must also be deleted. So I am planning to achieve the same using triggers. The trigger will be only on `DELETE` condition.

The application from which I am achieving the same runs 4-5 times a day. So, at the start of the application, I am adding the triggers and on exit of application, I am dropping the triggers (because triggers slow down the database performance).

This too much frequent adding and dropping triggers is OK for Postgres or is there any better idea to achieve the same?

There are other applications as well which keep on running and they are using the database. Other applications do only `INSERT` and `UPDATE` operations. Only my application does the deletion part. It is a utility for daily cleanups.

Comment: Can't you use stored procedures or functions?

Comment: Did you actually observe the slow-down?

Comment: If you quit the application then nothing is using the database, so how can the database be "slow" then? And how did you measure the slowdown _with_ triggers? An how big is the impact that you measured?

Comment: In what way does a trigger that is not fired slow down database performance?

Comment: If the other applications never fire DELETE statements the triggers will have no impact on performance.

Answer (score -1):

You may use

```
ALTER TABLE tblname ENABLE\DISABLE TRIGGER
```

Comment: _'This too much frequent adding and dropping triggers is OK for postgres or is there any better idea to achieve the same ?'_ - do you have anything to add there?

Comment: Yeap. :) It's unwise to add & drop triggers frequently.

Comment: The OP is actually asking whether it's OK to add and drop triggers frequently. If you believe it's unwise to do that, perhaps it's a little unwise not to include your opinion in your answer :) If you do include that, however, then it will also be a good idea to elaborate why, cheers.